# Lemma on arithmetic and geometric means

Tags: proof-verification

Randomly thought about this in bio class today, did some quick work. Is this identity known and does it have any applications?

---

- Let $\text{am}(a,b)$ denote the arithmetic mean of two numbers.
- Let $\text{gm}(a,b)$ denote the geometric mean of two numbers.

Consider two arbitrary numbers $x$ and $y$.

**Lemma: $\text{am}(\text{am}(x,y),\text{gm}(x,y))=[\text{am}(\sqrt x,\sqrt y)]^2$**

Proof:

We have the following two identities:

- $\text{am}(x,y)=\frac{x+y}{2}$
- $\text{gm}(x,y)=\sqrt{xy}$

$$\implies\text{am}\left(\frac{x+y}{2},\sqrt{xy}\right)=[\text{am}(\sqrt x,\sqrt y)]^2$$

$$\implies\frac{\frac{x+y}{2}+\sqrt{xy}}{2}=\left[\frac{\sqrt x+\sqrt y}{2}\right]^2$$

$$\implies\frac{x+y+2\sqrt{xy}}{4}=\frac{x+y+2\sqrt{xy}}{4}$$

This completes the proof.

Comment: AM GM inequality is known by almost everyone

Comment: it is applicable in many problems where the minimum of a multivariable expression is needed under a certain domain

Comment: The notion of combining arithmetic and geometric means is covered [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic%E2%80%93geometric_mean). $\text{am}(\text{am}(x,y),\text{gm}(x,y))$ is called $a_1$ in the article. $g_1$ would be $\text{gm}(\text{am}(x,y),\text{gm}(x,y))$